# MySql - vacancy query and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Got a problem finding vacancies over a week in a booking system.
I can get the NULL items no problem, but the issue is that bookings can have any of four values: enquiry, optioned, paid or cancelled.
(status in example below - values being 1,2,3 or 4)

So if in a week I have any that are "enquiry, optioned or paid" then I do not show the item - it's regarded as in use.
If they are cancelled that counts as empty - *but* within that week I can have multiple bookings, so if another booking was "enquiry, optioned or paid" then the item is *not* empty for that week. 
There's my problem : I seem to need a GROUP BY on the subclause and then another GROUP BY conditional on that.

Here's what I have

```
SELECT unit_num FROM unitmap
LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings ON bookings.unit_ref_id=unitmap.unit_id
AND (bookings.end_d>='".$start."' AND bookings.start_d<='".$end."')
WHERE (bk_id IS NULL OR status>=4) 
GROUP BY unit_id
```

This is wrong in that I get the item if it has BOTH a cancelled and an 'active' booking, whereas I want to see it if it's ONLY got a cancelled (or is null). I've tried lots of things!

```
id     unit    datestart  dateend       status
1     21      2017-12-15   2017-12-30     2
2     21      2017-12-11   2017-12-12     4
3     13      2017-12-15   2017-12-30     4
4     13      2017-12-11   2017-12-12     4
5     14      2017-12-15   2017-12-30     2
```

For week starting 11 Dec:
Unit 21 would not show in vacancies table as it has an active booking (id 1 with status 2).
Unit 13 would show as both bookings were cancelled (status 4).
Unit 14 has an active booking (id 5 with status 2) so would not show.
(All the other unlisted units would show as they have a NULL booking id)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the query that gives you the bookings

```
SELECT unit_ref_id FROM bookings
 WHERE bookings.end_d>='".$start."' AND bookings.start_d<='".$end."' AND status in (1,2,3)
```

Right? Now join that to your units table, with a left join, and select only the ones that have no matching record on this booked units query.

```
SELECT unit_num
  FROM unitmap
       LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT unit_ref_id FROM bookings
            WHERE (bookings.end_d>='".$start."' AND bookings.start_d<='".$end."' AND status in (1,2,3))
        AS BookedUnits
        ON unitmap.unit_id = BookedUnits.unit_ref_id
WHERE BookedUnits.unit_ref_id is null
```

If the unit has any (1 or more) bookings that match those conditions in the first query, in the second query (without the where clause) that unit would show one or more times (once for each booking) with a unit_ref_id that is NOT null.  But the ones that have NO bookings will show only once, with a NULL in the BookedUnits.unit_ref_id.  The WHERE clause at the end then picks out only those that have no bookings - null BookedUnits.unit_ref_id.

Depending on your data and what you find most readable, you might be able to say `status < 4` rather than `status in (1,2,3)`.

You could add a `DISTINCT` qualifier to that inner query (`SELECT DISTINCT unit_ref_id FROM bookings...`).  Depending on your data and the queries you get (what start and end dates), that might be more efficient, but I doubt you will ever notice the difference one way or another.

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the detailed explanation - works a treat. 
That's a cunning inversion to get them all as NULLS

Comment: Ah - it did need the DISTINCT on the sub query - otherwise it was getting mismatches - in effect a GROUP BY.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that last comment - mismatches?.  It really should work just fine without the distinct, but maybe I am missing something.  Glad to help.  Would appreciate it if you accept it as the answer.

Comment: It was showing unwanted results - adding distinct stopped that. 
That 'tick to accept' is bad UX - it's invisible in the grey - needs words.